# The UID token does not work with "Behavior in No Results" from my view

Tags: views, 8

I created a view with "Global: Unfiltered Text" in "Behavior in No Results" of my view.

Here is its content :

```
<a href="/user/{{ uid }}/notifications"> 
   <span class="fa fa-commenting"></span>
</a>
```

This view displays the link (it is missing the uid) :

/user//notifications

But she should show the link :

/user/1/notifications

How to solve the problem ?

[image]

This view displays the "Message" aggregate. I want to display a badge on the icon to show the number of messages. If the user clicks on the icon, it is directed to :

/user/1/notifications

When there are no messages, I want the icon to be displayed without the badge. If the user clicks on the icon, it is directed to :

/user/1/notifications

Here is an export of my view :

```
uuid: c4871516-a522-46bf-b344-81ac16ea0e2c
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - user.role.authenticated
  module:
    - message
    - user
id: utilisateur_page_notification
label: 'Utilisateur page notification'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: message_field_data
base_field: mid
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: role
        options:
          role:
            authenticated: authenticated
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: none
        options:
          items_per_page: null
          offset: 0
      style:
        type: default
      row:
        type: fields
      fields:
        mid:
          table: message_field_data
          field: mid
          id: mid
          entity_type: null
          entity_field: mid
          plugin_id: field
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: number_integer
          settings: {  }
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
      filters: {  }
      sorts: {  }
      title: Notifications
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships:
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: message_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: Utilisateur
          required: false
          entity_type: message
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: standard
      arguments:
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: users_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: uid
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          default_action: default
          exception:
            value: all
            title_enable: false
            title: All
          title_enable: false
          title: ''
          default_argument_type: current_user
          default_argument_options: {  }
          default_argument_skip_url: false
          summary_options:
            base_path: ''
            count: true
            items_per_page: 25
            override: false
          summary:
            sort_order: asc
            number_of_records: 0
            format: default_summary
          specify_validation: false
          validate:
            type: none
            fail: 'not found'
          validate_options: {  }
          break_phrase: false
          not: false
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: user_uid
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - user
        - user.roles
      tags: {  }
  block_1:
    display_plugin: block
    id: block_1
    display_title: Block
    position: 2
    display_options:
      display_extenders:
        metatag_display_extender: {  }
      fields:
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: users_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: uid
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: true
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: number_integer
          settings:
            thousand_separator: ''
            prefix_suffix: true
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: field
        mid:
          id: mid
          table: message_field_data
          field: mid
          relationship: none
          group_type: count_distinct
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: true
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: number_integer
          settings:
            thousand_separator: ''
            prefix_suffix: true
          group_column: entity_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: null
          entity_field: mid
          plugin_id: field
        nothing:
          id: nothing
          table: views
          field: nothing
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: true
            text: "<a href=\"/user/{{ uid }}/notifications\"> \n   <span class=\"fa fa-commenting\"></span>\n   <span class=\"badge\">{{ mid }}</span>\n</a>"
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: false
          plugin_id: custom
      defaults:
        fields: false
        empty: false
        group_by: false
      empty:
        area_text_custom:
          id: area_text_custom
          table: views
          field: area_text_custom
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          empty: true
          tokenize: true
          content: "<a href=\"/user/{{ uid }}/notifications\"> \n   <span class=\"fa fa-commenting\"></span>\n</a>"
          plugin_id: text_custom
      group_by: true
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - user
        - user.roles
      tags: {  }
  page_1:
    display_plugin: page
    id: page_1
    display_title: Page
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders:
        metatag_display_extender: {  }
      path: user/%user/notifications
      menu:
        type: tab
        title: Notifications
        description: ''
        expanded: false
        parent: ''
        weight: 0
        context: '0'
        menu_name: account
      arguments:
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: users_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: uid
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          default_action: default
          exception:
            value: all
            title_enable: false
            title: All
          title_enable: false
          title: ''
          default_argument_type: current_user
          default_argument_options: {  }
          default_argument_skip_url: false
          summary_options:
            base_path: ''
            count: true
            items_per_page: 25
            override: false
          summary:
            sort_order: asc
            number_of_records: 0
            format: default_summary
          specify_validation: false
          validate:
            type: none
            fail: 'not found'
          validate_options: {  }
          break_phrase: false
          not: false
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: user_uid
        uid_1:
          id: uid_1
          table: users_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: uid
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          default_action: default
          exception:
            value: all
            title_enable: false
            title: All
          title_enable: false
          title: ''
          default_argument_type: raw
          default_argument_options:
            index: 1
            use_alias: false
          default_argument_skip_url: false
          summary_options:
            base_path: ''
            count: true
            items_per_page: 25
            override: false
          summary:
            sort_order: asc
            number_of_records: 0
            format: default_summary
          specify_validation: false
          validate:
            type: none
            fail: 'not found'
          validate_options: {  }
          break_phrase: false
          not: false
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: user_uid
      defaults:
        arguments: false
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - user
        - user.roles
      tags: {  }
```

Comment: You are stating yourself, that you are using the "no results" behavior for this rewrite. So it is used when there is no result for this field. As you are using the global text field this means there is no result for the row as well. Thus `{{ uid }}` is empty and will be replaced with an empty string. Please describe more detailed why you are using the no results behavior (what do you like to achieve?). Maybe you'll get help then.

Comment: @Mario Steinitz I updated my question

Comment: So the intention is clear. Additionally you should tell about your data structure (what kind of entity are the notifications), how your users and notifications are related (e.g. entity reference), and give some details about your view (what kind of view is it, aggregation settings if any, filters, ...). This group usually gives to the point help when you provide enough details and describe in detail what you did so far. I'll also try my best to help. But the options still are too broad.

Comment: @Mario Steinitz If I put the token "{{ arguments.uid }}" it displays the username in the link. If I put the token "{{ uid }}" it does not show the username of the user. It is not logical.

Comment: it's completely logical. {{ uid }} comes from the resultset. if you have no results, it's empty. {{ arguments.uid }} comes from the context. but the solution is easy, if you have the context already: change {{ arguments.uid }} to {{ raw_arguments.uid }}.